# If $\frac{a}{b}$ is irreducible, then the quotient of the product of any $2$ factors of $a$ and any $2$ factors of $b$ are irreducible.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

$a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$

Factors of $a$: $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$.

Factors of $b$: $b_1,b_2,...,b_m$

> Prove that if $\frac{a}{b}$ is irreducible, then
> $\frac{a_ia_j}{b_kb_l}$  is irreducible for all $i,j,k,l$.

I proved the case where $i=j, k=l$ using the fact that the square root of any non-perfect square is irrational.

I can't prove the more general case though.

**EDIT**: not just prime factors, just all the integer factors. E.g. 12: 1,2,3,4,6,12

Comment: When you write factors you mean prime factors?

Comment: @Landau Does it matter?

Comment: Don't switch between upper and lower case like that!

Comment: @Landau No, any integer factor.

Comment: @TonyK Whoops I fixed it now

Comment: Factors of coprimes remain coprime by $\ d\mid a_1 a_j\mid a,\ d\mid b_k b_l\mid b\Rightarrow d\mid a,b\,$ so $\,d = 1\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach : proof by contradiction.

Suppose that $\frac{a_i a_j}{b_k b_l}$ is not irreducible.
Then $\exists \;$ prime $\;p \;\ni p|(a_i \times a_j)$ and
$p|(b_k \times b_l) \Rightarrow$ 
$p|a$ and $p|b \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}$ is not irreducible.

Comment: Is this due to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic? If it is irreducible, then $a_i a_j = nb_k b_l$. So there exists a prime p that divides $a_i a_j$ and $nb_k b_l$ . Reductively; p divides some $c$ and $nd$. But how do you go from p divides $nd$ to p divides $d$? I'm just wondering how you went from the preposition to "there exists a prime...". Sorry, I'm pretty new to number theory to put it lightly.

Comment: @Simplex1 "Is this due to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?" : **yes**. Further, given that $(a_i \times a_j)$ divides $a$, since (by assumption) $p$ divides $(a_i \times a_j), p$ must divide any multiple of $(a_i \times a_j).$  Assuming that I have not misunderstood the posting, $a$ is a multiple of $(a_i \times a_j).$ The logic behind concluding that $p$ divides $b$ is identical.

Comment: Oh right that makes sense. Neat

Comment: @Simplex1 Actually it has nothing to do with FTA. Rather it follows immediately from the coprime hypothesis - see my comment on the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque Your approach is certainly valid.  However, my use of the FTA, as an alternative approach is also valid.  By the FTA, if $p ~| ~(a_i \times a_j)$ then $p$ shows up in the prime decomposition of $(a_i \times a_j).$  Therefore, WLOG, $p$ shows in the prime decomposition of $a_i$.  Therefore, since $a_i ~| ~a$, $p$ must show in the prime decomposition of $a$.  Therefore, $p ~| ~a.$

Comment: I didn't say it was not valid. You don't use the full power of FTA, only that every nonzero nonunit has a prime factor. But you don't need that. Just replace $p$ by *any* common factor $d$ and then you get the proof in my comment - which is much more general -  it works in *any* domain (even non-UFDs, rings without primes, etc).

Comment: And we don't need FTA to prove $\,p\mid a_i a_j\mid a\Rightarrow p\mid a.\,$ Rather, that follows by *transitivity* of divisibility.

Comment: There is however an ambiguity in the question, i.e. is $\,i=j\,$ allowed, i.e. can we repeat factors in $\,a_i a_j$ even if they were not repeated in $\,a?\,$ If so then we need to say a little more (e.g. use Euclid's Lemma), but we can still prove it using only gcd laws, without any use of FTA or primes.

Comment: @BillDubuque I was about to make the same point.  That is, I interpreted the question as allowing $(a) = 12, a_i = 4, a_j = 6.$  Then your transitivity of divisibility argument breaks down.

Comment: @BillDubuque Further, a subjective argument may be made that use of the prime numbers, as I did, provides an easier proof for the OP to understand.  Note the OP's 2nd comment, following my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Now that I review my comment following the answer, I realize that I (also) may have misinterpreted the original question.  But this begs the question: for a new student, what is the easiest argument to understand.

Comment: If the question doesn't allow repeated factors then the transitivity argument is both simpler and more general. If is does allow them then it is a comparison between using Euclid's lemma for prime vs. general divisors - not really much difference in complexity, but lots in generality - since the general form works in any domain. But we're beating a dead horse at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If a prime number $p$ divides both $a_i a_j$ and $b_k b_l$, then it divides $a_i$ or $a_j$ hence $a$, and it also divides $b_k$ or $b_l$ hence $b$. This is impossible hence there is no such prime number and $\frac{a_i a_j}{b_k b_l}$ is irreductible.

Comment: Does $p$ need to be prime though?

Comment: @Simplex1 For the implication $p | (a_i a_j) \Longrightarrow p | a_i \text{ or } p | a_j$, then yes, $p$ needs to be prime.

Comment: @Simplex1 For the logic behind Gribouillis' answer, yes, $p$ needs to be prime.  For the logic behind my alternative (proof by contradiction) approach, no, I could have structured my answer where $d$ is a common factor of $\frac{a_i a_j}{b_k b_l}.$  I simply used prime $p$ as a common factor because I thought that the logic behind my approach would **then** be more easily seen to be ir-refutable.

Answer (score 0):

If $\frac{a_ia_j}{b_kb_l}$ were reducible then there would exist a prime number $p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$a_ia_j=p\cdot\alpha\;$,

$b_kb_l=p\cdot\beta\;$.

So the prime number $p$ would be a factor of $a_i$ or $a_j$ and it would also be a factor of $b_k$ or $b_l$.

Consequently $p$ would be a factor of $a$ and a factor of $b$ too.

For this reason the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ would not be  irreducible and it is a contradiction.

So it is impossible that $\frac{a_ia_j}{b_kb_l}$ is reducible and it means that $\frac{a_ia_j}{b_kb_l}$ is irreducible.